# Prove the following set is compact in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, divergence-operator

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree greater than 1. Prove that the following set is compact:

$K(f)= ( z \in  \mathbb{C}: f(f(f(...f(z)...)))$ does not diverge )

Alternatively, the set of all complex numbers such that an infinite number of iterations by $f$ does not diverge ( not necessarily converge )

My attempt:

Setting this proof up I went with the “closed and bounded” approach. I believe I managed to get boundedness by appealing to the fact that after each iteration the degree of the polynomial will grow fast. However proving this set is closed has alluded me; I tried setting up a sequence that converges to a point and showing that point is in $K(f)$. While doing this I tried using the fact that each iteration is a polynomial, and hence, continuous, but this doesn’t give a straightforward explanation as to why the infinite iteration will not diverge.

Background: Complex Qual question  #$7$ (www.math.tamu.edu/graduate/phd/quals/ncomplex/a17.pdf)

Comment: To be specific, the question you have written and the question posed are slightly different. The question in the link specifies that $f^{[n]}(z)\not\to\infty$ whereas you only require it not diverge (which seems to be to saying that the iterations **do** converge).

Comment: Well that changes everything... do you have a reference for the notation?

Comment: Sean, the notation comes from the link you provided.

Comment: I mean for the notation’s meaning- not “tending” to $\infty$ does not imply it converges.

Comment: I'm saying **your** statement that the iterations do not diverge implies the iterations *do* converge. The statement: $f^{[n]}(z)\not\to\infty$ does *not* imply the iterations converge (since your statement and the linked question imply different things, their meaning cannot be equivalent).

Comment: Then what exactly does the linked statement say? (trying to avoid using latex)

Comment: The linked text can be boiled down to saying that the modulus does not approach infinity. If the modulus is 1 for example, the sequence might not converge but will still have modulus 1, so is a part of the set described.

Comment: Oh thanks Clayton! I’ll keep trying, but I’ll keep the question up and edit it if I run into anything else